# Reusing an expression in a comprehension

Tags: python, dictionary-comprehension

Is it possible to reuse a subexpression that might be large, or expensive to compute, or non-idempotent like a generator, in a comprehension?

Say there is a list of strings to be to converted to a dict:

```
items = ['ab: 1', 'cd: 2', 'ef:3']  ===>  {'ab': '1', 'cd': '2', 'ef': '3'}
```

A loop computes the "expensive" split expression once:

```
d = {}
for item in items:
    k, v = item.split(':', maxsplit=1)
    d.update({k.strip(): v.strip()})
```

A comprehension repeats the computation for each output element:

```
d = {x.split(':', maxsplit=1)[0].strip(): x.split(':', maxsplit=1)[1].strip() for x in items}
```

But the desired solution is a comprehension that computes the expression once and then reuses it:

```
d = {k.strip(): v.strip() for x in items for k, v in x.split(':', maxsplit=1)}     # Wrong - need an assignment
```

Can it be done?

Comment: In this instance you have `d = {k.strip(): v.strip() for x in items for k, v in [x.split(':')]}`, but I assume this doesn't generalize. Have you looked at https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/ ?

Comment: The problem isn't that it doesn't generalize, the problem is that it doesn't work.  That is a syntactically-correct comprehension, but it loops over the split output rather than assigning it.

Comment: You can't get rid of loops if you have multiple elements. The expensive operation in your toy example is the split, which only happens once (per element in `items` which is of course necessary). Additionally the `for k, v in [x.split(':')]` only has one loop iteration. It takes the one-element list `[['ab', '1']]` and uses tuple unpacking to map it onto `k` and `v`

Comment: PEP 572 is exactly what is needed - I'm running Python 3.7, but will install 3.8 to try it.  Shame it took that long to get implemented, it seems like the need for assignment expressions would have been obvious even in Python 2.  It was 40 years ago in C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't *need* a dictionary comprehension, the `dict` object already takes in tuples:

```
dict(map(str.strip, x.split(':')) for x in items)

# {'ab': '1', 'cd': '2', 'ef': '3'}
```

And this would be the dict comprehension if you want:

```
{k: v for k, v in [map(str.strip, x.split(':')) for x in items]}

# {'ab': '1', 'cd': '2', 'ef': '3'}
```

Comment: Thanks - comprensions are already in my toolbox, but I obviously need to put map in there too.

Comment: I've used that before - how did I miss it? `dict` will consume it all.

Answer (score 2):

```
a = ['ab: 1', 'cd: 2', 'ef:3']
```

Using generator expression with map and a dictionary *comprehension*.

```
In [46]: b = (map(str.strip,thing.split(':')) for thing in a)

In [47]: d = {k:v for (k,v) in b}

In [48]: d
Out[48]: {'ab': '1', 'cd': '2', 'ef': '3'}
```

Each item in `a` is split once and the items in the resultant list are stripped once. Execution of those functions is delayed till the dictionary *comprehension* is executed.